# Android-Studio won't start, NoClassDefFoundError com/intellij/openapi/diagnostic/Logger

Tags: android, linux, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying to run Android-Studio on a Debian Jessie machine, but it won't.
Just unpacked it, marked bin/studio.sh as executable and executed it.
All I get is the following stacktrace:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/diagnostic/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

No log is written or anything else. Already searched and tried various things (e.g. adding lib/openapi.jar manually to the classpath, etc) for more than an hour, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that there are no spaces in the path where Android Studio is installed.

Comment: there aren't an spaces in the path, it is /opt/androidstudio.